# Material table editable with condition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I was trying to create a material table:

1. I have three column, which are `Type`, `Mark`, and `Total`.
2. I implement the inline edit, user can edit the `total` only.
   [image]
3. When user click `add new` button, they can type in type, mark and total.
   [image]

I'm fine with the edit part.

For the add part, all column is editable now, but I want to do it like column is editable based on condition.

For example: If user fill in the type = "Deliver", the `mark` column should be disabled, user cannot edit that column. How can I do this?

Here is sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-qgtm0g?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: can u please add a sandbox? so I can do the coding there?

Comment: @ShakyaKarunathilake hi, Ive put my code into the sandbox and updated in question already.